# Horror short film about an impossible door in an apartment leading to a place with a creature

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror, short-film

A couple of years ago (I think some time after 2010), I watched a horror short film (presumably on one of the common video platforms like YouTube or Vimeo). I'm quite sure its original language was English. Its plot was as follows:

One day, a couple notice a door in their apartment they had never noticed before. On the other side of the wall, there is no door, so it is actually geometrically impossible for a door to be there. On the side with the door, maybe there is even a shelf or some other furniture partially blocking the door, which they first have to remove to open it - further supporting the idea that the door was not there before.

They open the door, and it leads to some kind of a forest, I think (or at least someplace out in the open that is not totally barren), where - if I recall correctly - they are attacked by a somewhat shapeless (blob-shaped? varying its shape? not sure anymore) monster that comes out of a hole.

I *think* only the woman comes back and the man doesn't survive the encounter, but I'm not sure about that part anymore.

Comment: It is not geometrically impossible for one side of a wall to have a door.  Imagine a hollow wall with a space between the two sides.  So a door on one side can lead to the interior space, which might be a secret passage of some sort.. If the hollow space between the two walls is shrunk to nothing, the two walls will be touching each other, the door on one side will open outwards to reveal the other wall.  Having the door lead to another dimension or planet or something is the impossible part.

Comment: @M.A.Golding: True, strictly speaking, you could have a door lookalike just on one side of even a thin wall. But that's not something you would normally find in a regular building. As far as I remember, it was conveyed quite clearly in the short film that already the mere existence of the door and the lack of a door on the opposing side of the wall seemed baffling to the protagonists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally found it again!

It is **Strange Thing** from 2013.

Most of the aspects I had listed from memory were accurate, except for:

- It was not shown what was on the other side of the wall opposite of the door; instead it was shown explicitly that the door had appeared over night.
- The man does come back.

  > Somehow. Or something like him.

Here is the **film on Vimeo**: https://vimeo.com/88690818

Scifi-related fun fact: I was totally unaware (or had completely forgotten) the tidbit that the protagonists are wearing Starfleet-themed bathrobes.